# Clustering of Tags

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset (~80k rows) that contains a comma-separated list of tags (skills), for example:

```
python, java, javascript,
marketing, communications, leadership,
web development, node.js, react
...
```

Some are as short as 1, others can be as long as 50+ skills. I would like to cluster groups of skills together (Intuitively, people in same cluster would have a very similar set of skills)

First, I use `CountVectorizer` from `sklearn` to vectorise the list of words and perform a dimensionr reduction using `SVD`, reducing it to 50 dimensions (from 500+). Finally, I perform `KMeans` Clustering with `n=50` , but the results are not optimal -- Groups of skills clustered together seems to be very unrelated.

How should I go about improving the results? I'm also not sure if `SVD` is the most appropriate form of dimension reduction for this use case.

Comment: Some remarks: (1) Try normalizing rows to unit length after 'CountVectorizer' (The intuition behind is that: when a person lists many skills, say 50+, she/he tends to add non relevant skills too, which is noise, and if no normalization is done before an algorithm that uses euclidean distance takes the data, this example of person would be far from all and therefore put in a cluster alone by the algorithm)  (2) Kmeans is well suited for unraveling spherical and balanced clusters which is rarely the case in real data. So I would try 'Spectral Coclustering' (available in sklearn) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the following approaches:

1. If you have enough data, try something like word2vec to get an embedding for each tag. You can use pre-trained models, but probably better to train on you own data since it has unique semantics. Make sure you have an OOV embedding for tags that don't appear enough times. Then use K-means, Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering, or other known clustering methods.
2. I would construct a weighted undirected-graph, where each tag is a node, and edges represent the number of times 2 tags appeared in the same list. Once the graph is constructed, I would use a community detection algorithm for clustering. Networkx is a very nice library in python that lets you do that.

For any approach (including yours), don't give up before you do some hyper-parameter tuning. Maybe all you need is a smaller representation, or another K (for the KMeans).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

All the TF-IDF, cosine, etc. only works well for very long texts, where the vectors can be seen to model a term frequency distribution with reasonable numeric accuracy. For short texts, this is not reliable enough to produce useful clusters.

Furthermore, k-means needs to put every record into a cluster. But what about nonsense data - say someone with the only skill "Klingon"?

Instead, use

### Frequent Itemset Mining

This makes perfect sense on tags. It identifies groups of tags that occur frequently together. So one pattern is, e.g., "python sklearn, numpy"; and the cluster is all the users that have these skills.

Note that these clusters will *overlap*, and some may be in no clusters. That is of course harder to use, but for most applications it makes sense that records can belong to multiple, or no, clusters.